# Problem with trait object storing its reference elsewhere

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I want to have a method `to_holder` of `SomeTrait` that'll store reference to the trait object to a struct, but the compiler forces `Self` of method `to_holder` to be `Sized`. Annotating `Self: Sized` does work, but that way I can't call `to_holder` from a trait object, which is troubling.

Here's the code:

```rust
trait SomeTrait {
    type Item;

    fn to_holder(&self) -> TraitObjectHolder<Self::Item> {
        TraitObjectHolder { obj: self }
    }
}

struct TraitObjectHolder<'a, T> {
    obj: &'a dyn SomeTrait<Item=T>,
}

struct SomeStruct<T> {
    item: T
}

impl<T> SomeTrait for SomeStruct<T> {
    type Item = T;
}

fn main() {
    let some_struct = SomeStruct { item: 0 };
    let some_struct = &some_struct as &dyn SomeTrait<Item=i32>;
    some_struct.to_holder();
}
```

And here's the compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:5:34
  |
5 |         TraitObjectHolder { obj: self }
  |                                  ^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = note: required for the cast from `Self` to the object type `dyn SomeTrait<Item = <Self as SomeTrait>::Item>`
help: consider further restricting `Self`
  |
4 |     fn to_holder(&self) -> TraitObjectHolder<Self::Item> where Self: Sized {
  |                                                          +++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I wonder that I'm just passing around references here, what does that has to do with whether `Self` is `Sized`?

Actually, it seems if I don't use associated function, things will be fine

```rust
fn to_holder<T>(x: &dyn SomeTrait<Item=T>) -> TraitObjectHolder<T> {
    TraitObjectHolder { obj: x }
}
```

Think you might need it, I'll also mention a bit of my original problem .

I'm writing a toy matrix calculating library, there is a trait `Mat` and many concrete types that implements `Mat`, for example, a `DataMatrix` holding the data and a `SliceMatrix` referring to slice of whatever matrix type that implements `Mat`.

Now, I want a method on `Mat` called `row` that returns a `SliceMatrix` referring to a row of that `Mat` trait object, but rust just doesn't allow me to call `row` on a trait object.

Comment: Hint: what if `Self` is `[T]`?